# Is there a function that finds the shortest path between two nodes?

Tags: python, function, networkx, shortest-path

Using python, is there a function that allows me to find the shortest distance between two nodes in a networkx graph. The function itself cant be from networkx.
Essentially what im asking, is there an alternative function for networkx.shortest_path_length() without actually using NetworkX. I've looked at the source code and it also has nx functions.

Comment: Any specific reason why you can't use the `shortest_path_length` function from networkx?

Comment: You're welcome to write one yourself, plenty of implementations of Dijkstra's in Python online.

Comment: @perl Well i am trying to write a code to calculate the distance matrix, and the rule is we can only use nx.adjacency_matrix() and no other function from nx

Comment: If you ask homework questions on stackoverflow, you should explain what you've tried.  Note that the Dijkstra's algorithm in the answer below isn't what you are expected to do.  It's clear that you're being asked to figure out the distance matrix using the adjacency matrix.  So you need to look to see what the relation is between the adjacency matrix (and powers of it) and paths between nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I did try a few things out in terms of working out the distance matrix. I started with allowing myself to use nx functions and manged to compute the distance matrix however I became stuck when i tried to find an alternative to the shortest path length function. Then i realised i didnt really need the adjacency matrix to define the function so reached a dead end with this method. Your hint about the powers of the adjacency matrix is also something i came across but quickly became confused with since the output of using powers on an adjacency matrix gives me the walks

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, [Dijkstra’s algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). The algorithm creates a tree of shortest paths from the starting vertex, the source, to all other points in the graph.

```
def dijkstra(self, src): 

    dist = [sys.maxint] * self.V 
    dist[src] = 0
    sptSet = [False] * self.V 

    for cout in range(self.V): 
        u = self.minDistance(dist, sptSet) 
        sptSet[u] = True

        for v in range(self.V): 
            if self.graph[u][v] > 0 and sptSet[v] == False and dist[v] > dist[u] + self.graph[u][v]: 
                    dist[v] = dist[u] + self.graph[u][v] 

    self.printSolution(dist)
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, i seem to be struggling with applying this code, a syntax error comes up with the line that ends in "False and"

Comment: I won't edit the code posted, but you should be able to figure out what formatting error was made in it.   But be aware, this isn't the approach you are expected to use if you've been told to use the adjacency matrix.